# XML Data Search

Tags: .net, xml, xpath

I have XML (Static Data) with size of 30 KB. It has multiple sub-fields at each level. My requirement is to  search for an element which matches to my input and retrieve it's sbu-fields. I'll not do any data manipulations on top of it and update the file. In this case which is will give better performance XPATH or XML Serialize in .Net?

Many of the resources says XML serialize would be good but I'm not sure which one to choose for my situation.

Answer (score 0):

Using the newer types in `System.Xml.Linq` you can efficiently query your XML data using LINQ queries without code bloat.

Here's a good starting place: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx